# Resolving alias in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, gojs

I am trying to resolve an alias in webpack but can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.  I am using a library called GoJS.  I have the below code in my module.exports of webpack:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            go: path.resolve(__dirname, './go.min.js')
        }
    }
```

This file is in my root project directory for now.  At the top of my ES6 module I have:

```
import go from 'go';
```

I have also tried:

```
var go = require("go");
```

The library does seem to be loading.  If I console.log(go) within the module, it returns an empty object.  Do I need to load this file a different way because of how it is designed?  Or is something wrong with my webpack settings?

[Here is the javascript file I am trying to load](http://app.processplan.com/resources/gojs/go.min.js)

Comment: If you try loading an up to date version of GoJS, is it still an issue?

Comment: That worked!!!  Is there something with the way the older version js file is formatted that is causing this?  Due to the way GoJS licensing works, I am not sure we can update.  We are looking into it though.

Comment: GoJS has updated its handling of AMD modules/require/imports, so I suspect the only way to fix this may be to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by updating GoJS to a later (1.5 or beyond probably) version, as it handles modules/requires/imports differently after that.